# Why does EF translate a Contains method call to Exists clause instead of In Clause?

Tags: entity-framework

When I create this query:

```
context.Orders.Where(x => context.Customers.Where(c => c.PersonID == 
10002).Select(c => c.CustomerID.Value).Contains(x.CustomerID.Value)).ToList();
```

I Expect it to create a query like this:

```
select * from Orders where CustomerID in (select CustomerID from Customers 
Where PersonID = 10002)
```

But the generated query is equivalent to:

```
select * from Orders o where Exists(select 1 from Customers c where
c.PersonID = 10002 and c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID)
```

this is a very simple query which could be written as:

```
context.Orders.Where(x => x.Customer.PersonID == 10002).ToList()
```

but my actual scenario cannot be. Also, for this simple query, the execution time is not different, but in more complex cases, the expected query runs much faster.

How can I force EF to use the query the way I want it to?

Comment: Are you sure about your expected query, it is not equivalent to your actual query?  Note that you say "OrderID in..." but your actual query is equivalent to "CustomerID in...".  Which one do you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've actually made up all the queries above, to express the situation. My actual queries are very complicated. I'm completely sure about the problem itself.

Answer (score 2):

My theory is that EF does not natively support `Contains`, but it does support `Any`.  As a hack, it translates your expression into the equivalent `Any` expression, which translates into an `Exists` expression in Sql.

My problem with that approach is that the sql query is messier than it needs to be (your issue), and I have also found examples where the database cannot optimize as well as it could.

The workaround that I use is to replace the `Contains` with an inner `Join`.  So your example becomes:

```
from c in context.Customers
join o in context.Orders on o.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
where c.PersonId = 10002
select o;
```

(Sorry, I know you are using lambda expressions but I'm not sure how to write joins using those).